# Storing a lot of text / string data strategies - analysis and solution

Tags: sql-server-2016, storage, database-size, string

I have a LOB application backed by SQL Server 2016.

Over the past few weeks, theres been issues whereby the SQL Server start throwing timeout errors - which has led to a bit more digging into the database, running some fixes etc.

As part of this, I've realised that ~85% of the 10GB database is messages. The system will process and store email communications back and forth and the HTML body of emails is being stored. The attachments are being split off and saved as S3 blobs so isn't an issue.

Given there's ~1 million records, ~in 6 months taking up ~8.5GB the rate of growth is a concern, from backups, to additional overheads in the coming years. I may be able to get a business case to delete old messages but this would be political rather the technical.

I've taken a copy and tested compression on the table, but it's had minimal impact... The next option, is to have the application compress and decompress the string as required but that will require quite a bit of scoping and testing.

Is there a best practise method to manage this? Put them (the messages) in a separate file group? Or a separate database altogether!? What is the best means for the storage of large strings of text?

Comment: How exactly did you test compressing the data? PAGE and ROW-level? Or using some built-in functions like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql?

Comment: Both page and row level... Both took off about 500 mb on the table size. I've not tried the function, and something like that may be better suited to process in the front end.

Comment: That's why I wanted to ask if you'd tried it yet. A lot less work, and would be a good proof of concept before rearchitecting the front end.

Comment: I'll give it a go tomorrow!

Comment: OK, tried and similar to the initial tests on the front end as both are using GZip compression. They both knock-about 5GB of the table size so well worth the exercise. Running it through a function means that the front end which uses EF will need to modified to use a sproc or similar... I assume there's native way to compress on an INSERT / UPDATE and decompress on SELECT unless via a SPROC?

Comment: You can use `COMPRESS` / `DECOMPRESS` in a stored procedure or directly from the code, depending on where you want to make the change.